# Advanced observer pattern ( mutual ) alternative

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

Suppose there is a class Data, it does not only contain data, which can and will be modified, it also contains important member functions that build upon the contained data member.

Further suppose there is a class HandleData, that gets a pointer to a Data instance. HandleData takes the Data and computes some important member Numbers ( already at initialization ). The computation of numbers during initialization and changing of data is important, because computing them with function member calls over and over again is costly ( for example performing integrations ).
If Data changes, the HandleData shall adapt to the changes by updating the numbers.

So far the problem is just a observer pattern. Now HandleData also feeds another class called TreatHandleData, such that changes of Data imply changes in HandleData, which again shall imply changes in the TreatHandleData. In all cases, to reduce computation time, some numbers must be initialized each time Data/HandleData changes.

The mess seems to be complete if all of these classes need to be copyable.

**I would really like to see some alternatives to what I have wrote below. Especially because in my case all classes must be derived from one. It just does not seem to be right.**

My simple attempt is:

```
#include <algorithm> // remove
#include <memory>    // shared_ptr
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>  // cout, cerr, endl
#include <vector>

class MutualObserver
{
public:

  MutualObserver() {}

  // copy ctor resets the list of observers
  MutualObserver(const MutualObserver & src) : observer(0) {}

  virtual ~MutualObserver() {};

  // assign op. must be empty to not have a list of observers that persists
  MutualObserver& operator = ( const MutualObserver &rhs ) { return *this; }

  // adds observer
  void add ( MutualObserver * o )
  {
    bool good = true;
    for ( uint i = 0; i<observer.size(); i++)
      if ( observer[i] == o ) good = false;

      if ( good && (o != NULL) ) observer.push_back(o);
  }

  // removes observer
  void remove ( MutualObserver * o )
  {
    if ( o == NULL )
      std::cout<<" in Data::remove - observer is NULL "<<std::endl;

    bool good = true;
    for ( uint i = 0; i<observer.size(); i++)
      if ( observer[i] == o ) good = false;

    if (good && o!=NULL )
      observer.erase
        ( std::remove( observer.begin(), observer.end(), o),observer.end() );
  }

  /// updates obserer o
  void update_observer ( MutualObserver * o )
  {
    for ( uint i = 0; i<observer.size(); i++ )
      if  ( observer[i] == o ) observer[i]->update_yourself();
  }

  /// updates all observers
  void update_all_observers ()
  {
    for (uint i = 0; i<observer.size(); i++)
    {
      observer[i]->update_yourself();
    }
  }

  /// updates all important members esp. of derived classes
  /// observer method, should be implemented for all observers
  virtual void update_yourself () {}

protected:
  std::vector<MutualObserver*> observer;

};


class Data : public MutualObserver
{
public:
  Data () : A(42.) {}
  void setA ( double x ) { A = x; update_all_observers(); }
  double getA () { return A; }
  double multiply ( double x ) { return A * x; } 

private:
  double A;  
};


class HandleData : public MutualObserver
{
  double important_variable;
  std::shared_ptr<Data> mySource;

public:
  HandleData ( std::shared_ptr<Data> source ) 
    :  mySource(source), important_variable(0.)
  {
    assert( source != NULL );
    mySource->add(this); 
    update_yourself();
  }

  HandleData ( const HandleData &src ) 
    :  MutualObserver(src), mySource( src.mySource ),
       important_variable( src.important_variable )
  {
    assert( mySource != NULL );
    mySource->add(this); 
    update_yourself();
  }

  virtual ~HandleData() { if ( mySource!=NULL ) mySource->remove(this); }

  virtual void update_yourself ()
  {
    double A = mySource->getA();
    important_variable = A *2.*3.14;
  }

  double getVariable() const { return important_variable; }
};


class TreatHandleData : public MutualObserver
{
  double important_variable;
  std::shared_ptr<HandleData> mySource;

public:
  TreatHandleData ( std::shared_ptr<HandleData> source ) 
    :  mySource(source), important_variable(0.)
  {
    assert( source != NULL );
    mySource->add(this); 
    update_yourself();
  }

  TreatHandleData ( const TreatHandleData &src ) 
    :  MutualObserver(src), mySource( src.mySource ), 
       important_variable( src.important_variable )
  {
    assert( mySource != NULL );
    mySource->add(this); 
    update_yourself();
  }

  virtual ~TreatHandleData() { if ( mySource!=NULL ) mySource->remove(this); }

  virtual void update_yourself ()
  {
    double A = mySource->getVariable();
    important_variable = A * 365.;
  }

  double getVariable() const { return important_variable; }
};

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Data> observable ( new Data() );
  std::shared_ptr<HandleData> observer ( new HandleData(observable) );
  std::shared_ptr<TreatHandleData> myTHD ( new TreatHandleData(observer) );

  // copy
  std::shared_ptr<Data> observable2 ( new Data( *observable ) );
  std::shared_ptr<HandleData> observer2 ( new HandleData(*observer) );
  std::shared_ptr<TreatHandleData> myTHD2 ( new TreatHandleData(*myTHD) );

  std::cout << "initial Data:            "<< observable->getA() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "initial HandleData:      "<< observer->getVariable() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "initial TreatHandleData: "<< myTHD->getVariable() << std::endl;

  std::cout << " COPY: " << std::endl;

  std::cout << "initial Data:            "<< observable2->getA() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "initial HandleData:      "<< observer2->getVariable() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "initial TreatHandleData: "<< myTHD2->getVariable() << std::endl;

  double a = 99.31232;
  std::cout << " Changing A to " << a << std::endl;
  observable->setA( a );  
  std::cout << " (diff) changed Data:            "<< observable->getA() << std::endl;
  std::cout << " (diff) changed HandleData:      "<< observer->getVariable() << std::endl;
  std::cout << " (diff) changed TreatHandleData: "<< myTHD->getVariable() << std::endl;

  std::cout << " COPY: " << std::endl;

  std::cout << " (same) changed Data:            "<< observable2->getA() << std::endl;
  std::cout << " (diff) changed HandleData:      "<< observer2->getVariable() << std::endl;
  std::cout << " (same) changed TreatHandleData: "<< myTHD2->getVariable() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Result is:

initial Data:            42

initial HandleData:      263.76

initial TreatHandleData: 96272.4

COPY:

initial Data:            42

initial HandleData:      263.76

initial TreatHandleData: 96272.4

Changing A to 99.3123

(diff) changed Data:            99.3123

(diff) changed HandleData:      623.681

(diff) changed TreatHandleData: 96272.4

COPY:

(same) changed Data:            42

(diff) changed HandleData:      623.681

(same) changed TreatHandleData: 96272.4

as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you do not want to recompute the data on HandleData and TreeHandleData on every getter call since the computation is expansive.

Why not using a lazy update approach were the getter check if the underlying data has changed and recompute only in that case. This way you would not need to use the observer pattern at all.